# Why is dictionary.get() returning values of all the dictionary entries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

The below program is an example to test the execution of print() using dictionary.get().

**Code:**

```
miles_between_oil_change = 7500
miles_warning = 500
miles_notify = miles_between_oil_change - miles_warning


def validInput(initial_mileage, final_milege):
    if initial_mileage > final_milege:
        return False
    return True


"""
Return values:
    0 - User doesn't need to change oil
    1 - User needs to change oil soon
    2 - User needs to change oil immediately
"""


def userToBeNotified(initial_mileage, final_mileage):
    miles_travelled = final_mileage - initial_mileage
    if miles_travelled < miles_notify:
        return 0
    elif miles_travelled > miles_notify:
        return 2
    else:
        return 1


def readInput():
    previous_mileage = int(input('Enter mileage of last oil change: '))
    current_milege = int(input('Enter current mileage: '))
    return previous_mileage, current_milege


def main():
    previous_mileage, current_milege = readInput()
    if not validInput(previous_mileage, current_milege):
        print('Invalid entry - Current mileage is less than mileage last changed')
        exit()

    user_notification = userToBeNotified(previous_mileage, current_milege)
    switcher = {
        0: print("User doesn't need to change oil"),
        1: print("User needs to change oil soon"),
        2: print("User needs to change oil immediately"),
    }
    switcher.get(user_notification)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
Enter mileage of last oil change: 5000
Enter current mileage: 13000
User doesn't need to change oil
User needs to change oil soon
User needs to change oil immediately
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Enter mileage of last oil change: 5000
Enter current mileage: 13000
User needs to change oil immediately
```

I tried calling switcher.get() assuming it'll print only the statement matching the key value. However, I see that all the values of all the entries in the dictionary are printed.

Comment: Remove the `print` from your `switcher` dictionary and instead have the values as strings. Then use `print` in your final statement: `print(switcher.get(user_notification))`

Comment: `.get` isn't returning all the values. It is returning the particular value associated with that key, although note, all of those values are `None`. *Your code* prints all those strings, however, because that is what using the `print` function does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.get()` call isn't what causes anything to print, it's the creation of the dictionary where you are calling print. If you reduce your code to only be the dict creation and run it, you'll still see all three `print`s. Try running this:

```
def main():
    switcher = {
        0: print("User doesn't need to change oil"),
        1: print("User needs to change oil soon"),
        2: print("User needs to change oil immediately"),
    }


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When you write `print('message')` you are immediately calling `print`. Similarly the line

```
s = print('message')
```

will immediately `print` `message`. Since `print` returns `None`, the result will be `s = None`. You're doing something similar in the dict creation.

---

You can replace the `print` call with the string itself. Then you retrieve the string from the dict, and print that

```
    switcher = {
        0: "User doesn't need to change oil",
        1: "User needs to change oil soon",
        2: "User needs to change oil immediately",
    }
    print(switcher[user_notification])
```

If your intention is to simulate a switch statement rather than represent the options in data, you have a couple options

You can use and else-if ladder

```
    user_notification = userToBeNotified(previous_mileage, current_milege)
    if user_notification == 0:
        print("User doesn't need to change oil")
    elif user_notification == 1:
        print("User needs to change oil soon")
    elif user_notification == 2:
        print("User needs to change oil immediately")
```

or, if you have access to python 3.10+, you can use `match`

```
    user_notification = userToBeNotified(previous_mileage, current_milege)
    match user_notification:
        case 0:
            print("User doesn't need to change oil")
        case 1:
            print("User needs to change oil soon")
        case 2:
            print("User needs to change oil immediately")
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. 
I've tried this, and it works. 
However, I'm trying to understand Python's behavior in case print() OR other commands are provided as a dict value.

Comment: @RahulB `dict` maps keys to values. The values in your original dictionary are not the `print` calls, but the *results* of the `print` calls. Which is `None` in each case. The `print` function prints its arguments and returns `None`. The `print` is executed during the definition of the dictionary (it must be, so its return value can be obtained and stored in the dictionary). That's why all three messages are being printed. They're printed when you define the dictionary.

Comment: @RahulB the fundamental thing is that you don't provide "commands". Dictionaries hold *objects*. An *expression in source code* will *evaluate to an object*. So `print('hi')` is an expression, it *evaluates to `None`*, (since `print` is a function that returns `None`), it also has the side-effect of writing to the standard output device (the results of which you generally see in your terminal). On the other hand, `"hi"` is an expression just by itself, a *string literal expression*, that evaluates to a `str` object.